# How to fork in GIT but not be allowed to push back to the origin remote

Tags: git, collaboration

I have a student coming in to help on a project for a month. I want him to fork the repository but then work on the code locally and not be able to push changes until I have reviewed and tested them all. How is this accomplished through GIT? Note we're running Windows and I have been using the GIT Extensions GUI and everything is on a LAN (no GIThub etc yet). Also there is a `--bare` repo on our server.

I can make it work by having him clone the bare repo and then on his local repo, delete the remote repo. Is that a reasonable thing to do? Will he later be able to merge his code back in by remote adding the repo again?

Comment: Is the *server* also on Windows?

Comment: @Makoto yes everything is Windows.

Comment: In this case, you're not going to want a pure Git solution.  I'm unfamiliar with the world of Windows servers and how one would install a Git server there, but the keyword(s) you're looking for are either Gitosis or Gitolite (likely Gitolite).  Git alone can't manage this for you.

Comment: Gitolite is a piece of poorly designed code, we used to use it. Overly complicated, not functional. I'd recommend gitlab over gitolite

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he will. But it is possible to write a hook script on the "server" git (`pre-receive` one,for example), which will refuse to merge the commit if it meets certain criteria. This is basically what all the git frameworks(GitLab, Stash, GitHub) do.

For more information refer to http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Thanks, could you provide an example of how such a script would be written?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a git guru, but FWIW here are my thoughts...

Ultimately, because the main repo resides on a LAN and is being accessed directly by the clients, I don't think you're going to find a solution that implements any kind of access controls like git servers (eg. github and bitbucket) would provide.

Howwever, all is not lost.

Why not have your student clone the main repo, create a new branch and work in that new branch? He can even push that branch back up to the main repo, which gives you the ability to review his work more easily. If other people are checking work into the master branch than your student will be able to easily fetch that work and merge it into his branch, so if he's breaking anything, he'll find out pretty quickly. Eventually, when you are ready to review and merge his work, you can have him push his changes (ie. his branch) into the main repo. You can then merge master into that branch, check that everything works as it is supposed to and, assuming it does, you can then simply merge his branch into master.

This will all work fine as long as he doesn't switch branches back to master. But the great thing about git is that even if he does switch back to master, AND commits changes, AND pushes them up to the main repo, you can always roll them back. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a pretty good idea. It sounds like those pre-receive hooks mentioned by Ojomio could get the access control going but then I'd have to learn how to do that and your way sounds a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a reasonable thing to do? Will he later be able to merge his code back in by remote adding the repo again?

That can be done without problem.

But a better solution could be to give him only a read access to the bare repository on the lan. That way, he could still get the newest code and adapt it's development with the latest version.

Or even better have another bare repository where he could write and that you add as a remote in your repository and that way you could follow it's development and integrate it's development (you do the buffer ;-))

Comment: The read/wrote access is apparently not an option for our network / folder structure according to our IT guys. I'm not going to fight with them over it. Thanks anyway.